# Is there a notion of "degree of discontinuity" in topology?

Tags: general-topology

We can defined the property of continuous functions between topological spaces. however, some discontinuities are worse than others. For example, if we have two functions $f,g:\{A,B,C\}\to \mathbb Z$, with the obvious topologies on these sets, and we know that $f(A)=1, f(B)=2, f(C)=4$, while $g(A)=0, g(B)=-4, g(C)=5$. Then in some sense, $g$ is "more discontinuous", since firstly, it goes down and up again, and secondly, it is discontinuous at multiple points, thirdly, the points are "farther away".

Comment: From the point of topology, there's no difference between the set $\{1,2\}$ and the set $\{1,100\}$. While the second has a bigger difference between the elements, "difference" is a term that is alien to topology. And so is "direction".

Comment: Topology is not going to give you the notion of "discontinuous" you are seeking here.  All your spaces are discrete, and every function between discrete topological spaces is continuous, and not discontinuous in any way.  If you have metric spaces, you maybe want to look at notions like distortion, or the best Lipschitz constant for a function (and its inverse?).

Comment: @celtschk, I noticed the curly brackets in $\{A,B,C\}$ didn't appear. Do you still agree with your statement? Here's why I intuitively think topology can say something about it: if we have the set $\{ -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3\}$ with the standard topology on it, then $2$ is "closer" to $0$, than $3$ is to $0$, because every neighbourhood of $0$ that contains $3$, also contains $2$, but not the other way around. Doesn't that allow us to define a "degree of discontinuity" purely based on topology?

Comment: @Programmer2134: Yes. Topology is exactly what you get if you *forget* about things like difference. All topology sees from the set $\{-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}$ is a set of seven separated elements. As far as topology is concerned, it could as well be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^7$, where any pair of vectors has the same distance. Topology cannot see the difference between both.

Comment: @celtschk, but if we have the standard topology on this set, then $0$ has the neighborhouds $\{0\}, \{0,1\},\{-1,0,1\}, \{0,2\},...$. Two of these neighbourhoods are $\{0,1,2\}$, and $\{0,1,2,3\}$, But there is no neighbourhood of $0$ that contains $3$ but not $2$. Doesn't this allow us to say that $2$ is closer to $0$ than $3$ is to $0$?

Comment: @Programmer2134: Wrong, $\{0,3\}$ is indeed a neighbourhood of $0$ that does not contain $2$.

Comment: @celtschk, why do you say $\{0,3\}$ is a neighborhood of $0$? Of course we can define the discrete topology on the set, and then it is a neighborhood trivially. But I'm assuming the topology that is generated by saying "a subset $X$ of $\mathbb Z$ is an open set iff it is not the case that for some $x\in \mathbb Z,\nin X$ and some $y,z\in X$, we have $y<x<z$". This assumes the standard order on $\mathbb Z$, and rules out $\{0,3\}$ as an open set. (Note that we're not using a metric here, and really not even an order, since we can drop the order once the topology is generated).

Comment: What you describe is not a topology, as the union of open sets and the intersection of finitely many open sets is open, by the definition of topology. So if $\{-1,0\}$ and $\{3,4,5\}$ are open sets, then $\{-1,0\}\cup \{3,4,5\} =\{-1,0,3,4,5\}$ is also open, and if then $\{0,1,2,3\}$ is also open, then so is $\{-1,0,3,4,5\}\cap\{0,1,2,3\}=\{0,3\}$. Therefore you cannot have a topology in which all of $\{-1,0\}$, $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $\{3,4,5\}$ are open, but $\{0,3\}$ is not. Note that indeed the standard topology on $Z$ *is* the discrete topology.

Comment: @celtschk, Ah I was wrong. Interesting. So then we probably do need a metric, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a function $f: X \to M$ where $M$ is a metric space and $X$ is a first countable topological space. Take $x \in X$ and a neighborhood base $(U_n)_n$ for $x$ with $U_1 \supseteq U_2 \supseteq U_3 \supseteq \dots$. On each $U_i$, we can define the oscillation of $f$ as $\sup_{y \in U_n} f(y)- \inf_{y \in U_n} f(y)$. Then $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if the oscillation over $U_n$ goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. You can measure how discontinuous $f$ is at $x$ by looking at the $\limsup$ of the oscillation over $U_n$ as $n \to \infty$. You can check that this matches up with your intuition.

The example you gave is pretty weird. I'm assuming $A,B,C$ are the three points in the topological space. If you have a discrete space, it doesn't make sense to talk about how discontinuous something is. Like I wouldn't say $g$ is more discontinuous than $f$ in the example you gave.

Comment: Thank you. You say we cant say anything about how discontinuous a function is in a discrete space. Wouldn't you say a hash function is "highly discontinuous"? a hash function is an example of a discontinuous function between topological spaces (metric spaces in fact), correct?

Comment: @Programmer2134: For a typical hash function, I would think of the codomain as some finite set of integers, e.g. $\{0, \dots, 2^{256}-1\}$, with the obvious metric.  But what is the domain, and what metric is it equipped with?

Comment: let's say the domain is also a finite set of integers, or a finite string of letters.  the metric could be for example, "the amount of changes to letters that need to be made to turn string $x$ into string $y$"

Comment: @Programmer2134 I feel like you're not talking about continuity but rather variation. If you have some function $f: \{1,2,\dots,n\} \to \{1,2,\dots,m\}$, it seems you care about $\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} |f(j+1)-f(j)|$.

Answer (score 0):

For metric spaces there is the oscillation of $f$ at $x$ defined as

$$\operatorname{osc}(f,x) = \inf_{\delta >0} \operatorname{diam} f[B(x,\delta)] $$

see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_(mathematics))

It is $0$ iff $f$ is continuous at $x$. In your discrete example all fucntions are continuous. so no insight is gained.